# Django CreateView cancel with empty fields

Tags: python, django, crud, django-generic-views

I have a `CountryCreateView` for my `Country` model and I'm trying to add a cancel button to it. However if there isn't something filled out in every field and I press the cancel button, I get a pop-up that says `Please fill out this field`. When I press the cancel button, I don't care what's in the fields, I just want to go to the page I'm redirecting to. On top of this, I want this field non-requirement to be only for this. I don't want anything else to allow blank fields.

views.py:

```
class CountryCreateView(generic.edit.CreateView):
    model = Country
    fields = ['code', 'name']
    template_name_suffix = '_create'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if "cancel" in request.POST:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('appName:country_list'))
        else:
            return super(CountryCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

models.py:

```
class Country(AutoUpdateModel): # extends models.Model

    code = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=2, validators=[validate_nonempty, validate_string_length_two, validate_string_all_caps]) 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column="Name", validators=[validate_nonempty])
    # etc...
```

country_create.html:

```
{% extends "appName/base.html" %}


{% block content %}


    <h2 class="title">Create a new Country:</h2>

    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-secondary"/>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You want some fields to accept blank values and some fields should have a value mandatory. Is it so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check if this works - add **formnovalidate** to submit button in html

```
<input type="submit" formnovalidate name="cancel" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-secondary"/>
```